# Proving using contradiction

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have to prove that $P=0$ is a limit point of $U=\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$, how can this be proved using contradiction? I have to show it using open and closed balls.

I proceeded by using proof by contradiction.
Let for all $\epsilon>0$, $B_\epsilon(P)|P \cap U = \phi$.
But there exists some $\epsilon>0$ for which $B_\epsilon(P)|P \cap U \ne \phi$, which is a contradiction, meaning my assumption is wrong.
Hence, for every $\epsilon>0$, $B_\epsilon(P)|P \cap U \ne \phi$, meaning $0$ is a limit point of $U \subset{\mathbb{R}}$.

But, I know that for $0$ to  be a limit point of $U$, this condition needs to be satisfied for all $\epsilon>0$, not just one.

Can I still proceed with this method?

Comment: What does $B_\epsilon(P)|P \cap U$ mean? And what is the contracdition when you say that $B_\epsilon(P)|P \cap U$ is not the empty set for some $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is wrong.

If $0$ is not a limit point of $U$ then **there exists** $\epsilon >0$ such that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon )$ does not contain any point of $U$ (other than $0$). Now choose $n >\frac 1  {\epsilon}$ to see that $\frac  1n $ does belong to this interval and also to $U$. This is the contradiction you need to finish the proof.